# How can I read the *.xlsb file using php or lumen/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I wanted to read the *.xlsb file using lumen/laravel application, I have tried with "Maatwebsite" package but it not support to the *.xlsb file, please suggest.

Is there any other option?

I have tried with **EasyXLS** but unable to add the package of it on **ubuntu laravel project**, and second **PHPSpreadsheet** library returning the type not found error.

 If any one provide me the step by step guide for the above packages it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access an .xlsb file by php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880402/how-to-access-an-xlsb-file-by-php)

Comment: I have gone through this site but I am unable to find the package download or composer require, please can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup EasyXLS on Ubuntu with PHP follow the steps:

**Step 1**
Install EasyXLS for Java

**Step 2**
Install [PHP Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/)

**Step 3**
Add EasyXLS.jar to classpath. Be sure that you restarted the web server (Apache).

**Step 4**
Execute

```
$workbook = new java("EasyXLS.ExcelDocument");
```

to check if the jar is found.

**Step 5**
If the user that installed EasyXLS is different than the user used by the web server, change the user.home property:

```
System.setProperty("user.home", "/home/user_that_installed_easyxls");
```

or

```
System.setProperty("user.home", "/root");//if installed as root
```

**Step 6**
Read the xlsb file as in documentation:
https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/import-from-xlsb-file-format.html

Note: If you use Laravel, EasyXLS.jar must be also present in java classpath.

Answer (score -1):

I would look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370957/how-to-convert-xlsb-to-array-or-csv-using-php) at a similar stackoverflow post.

Usually when i want to read excel files i use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)
You could also restrict and not allow Xlsb files and just stick with xls files or other supported formats as seen [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)

**edit:**
 Should have read better. I understand you are having trouble with easyXLS. Looks to be a paid service. sorry about that.
I would recommend to not allow xlsb and force xlsx or other formats supported by PhpSpreadsheet, i can't find any support for xlsb
xlsb is easily converted to xlsx by just resaving them in microsoft excel.

Comment: It is not supporting **xlsb** format only accept **xls**, **xlsx** formats.

Comment: are you referring to the stackoverflow page i linked or phpspreadsheet?

Comment: I have tried with PhpSpreadsheet it returns me the type not found error. and for EasyXLS, I haven't find for PHP if you know the procedure can you explain it step by step with small example like, composer command and  use class and the function name?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22142833)

Comment: @commonsense you are right, still a bit new to this. not really an answer tho. sorry about that